# Pycharm color scheme for lines changed in file

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm for my python projects.  I don't know what happened but it used to show in the left margin/gutter which lines are new and which lines were from the original file.  I didn't (knowingly) change anything in my preferences so I don't know why it's not coloring the differences anymore.

I've checked

Editor>General>Other>Highlight modified lines in gutter

but that isn't highlighting anything.  I've played with the settings in the preferences but it's not helping.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: check whether your project in PyCharm is under version control in `Settings -> Version Control`. Probably it is not set to be tracked, thus it doesn't know what changed and what to highlight

Comment: @iulian, thx for your suggestion.  that might be my initial problem, i didn't enter any info for our repo but it still colored b/c of which dir I had selected.  I'll try to enter for all my future projects so I don't run into this problem.  thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm an idiot.  Looks like when opening directories/projects, if I don't choose the correct directory with the git metadata for the repo, it doesn't show the color differences.

Mods can close this question since this is due to operator error/stupidity.